# Getting webpack compilation error when using Faker 7.6.0 in Cypress 12.5.1

Tags: javascript, cypress, faker

Trying to use faker for random data generation.

Under support > e2e.js added
cy.faker = require('faker');

In spec file "TestRandomData.cy.js"

```
import {faker} from "faker-js/faker"
const cityName = faker.address.cityName();

describe('Test Random Data', function () {
     it('Faker random  data', () => {
       cy.log(cityName)
    })
})
```

Getting below error:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'faker-js/faker' in 'C:\Automation\cypress\e2e'
resolve 'faker-js/faker' in 'C:\Automation\cypress\e2e'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: C:\Automation\package.json (relative path: ./cypress/e2e)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Answer (score 0):

`cypress/support/e2e.js` updated

```
cy.faker = require('@faker-js/faker');
```

Made the following updates in `TestRandomData.cy.js`

```
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
const cityName = faker.address.cityName();

describe('Test Random Data', function () {
    it('Faker random  data', () => {
       cy.log(cityName)
    })
})
```